# Grab Label Text from ASP ListView in VB SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have ListView1 with the following :

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>Notification:
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("NotificationID") %>' runat="server" ID="NotificationIDLabel" Visible="False" />
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' runat="server" ID="CustomerIDLabel" Visible="False" />
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("NotificationText") %>' runat="server" ID="NotificationTextLabel" /></td>
<td>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlPromo" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL") %>'  ForeColor="#701A3C" runat="server">View</asp:HyperLink></td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteNotification" runat="server" Text="Clear" ForeColor="#701A3C" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="#331700" /></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I changed the btnDeleteNotification into a selected index change because I want to find out which NotificationID to delete in the SQL table. How could I grab the NotificationID of the selected row? I've tried every combination of VB I could think of to grab it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FindControl()` inside of the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, like this:

```
Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim theNotificationLabel As Label = CType(ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndex).FindControl("NotificationIDLabel"), Label)

    ' Grab the ID from the text of the label
    Dim theNotificationId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(theNotificationLabel.Text)
End Sub
```

> Note: If your list view is not named `ListView1`, then change it to whatever your list view is actually named.